# How to eliminate duplicate results in a view?

Tags: 8, views

I have a view in a D8 site displaying results of the content type "Projects", sorted by the taxonomy "Project area":

[image]

I'm getting duplicate results in my views output.

I've tried both setting the query settings to "Distinct", and turning aggregation on, neither of which removes the duplicates.

Is there a solution to this? I'm not so experienced with Drupal, so any simple explanations?

Comment: You seem to have Relationships in your Views. They often cause duplicates. It can happen when there are multivalue fields displayed each in its own row. Does duplicating disappear when you remove sorting? Try to pinpoint what is causing it by rebuilding the views step by step and checking each time.

Comment: Agree with @prkos duplicates are usually caused by the relationships. Its very hard to diagnose usually it's best to rebuild the relationships one at a time to find the cause, and then try to find an alternative.